# Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} f = L$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} f = L$.

1. Prove that $L = 0$.
2. Prove that $f$ has a limit at every point in $\mathbb{R}$.

I can show  $f(0)=0$, $f(−x)=−f(x)$ i.e an odd function. But how to prove the above. Please help.

Comment: Show that for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $f(1/n)=f(1)/n$. Then you can show $L=0$. For the second point note that $f(x)=f(x_0) + f(x-x_0)$, which allows you to compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x)$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: That should be an answer.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven How to show $f(1/n)=f(1)/n$

Comment: You have $$ f(1)=f(1/2 + 1/2)= 2 f(1/2)$$ Try to generalize this.

Comment: @CameronBuie In my opinion the OP should write the answer himself with the rough hint I gave, that way he gains understanding and (if he does it well) reputation as well.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: That 's a fair point!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note
$$
f(1) = f\Big(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\Big)
= f\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big) + f\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)
= 2\cdot f\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)
$$
By induction you can show that $f(1) = 2^n\cdot f\big(\frac{1}{2^n}\big)$. Since $\frac{1}{2^n}$ converges to $0$ for $n\to\infty$, you can conclude that $f(1)$ is not well-defined, if $L\neq 0$. Hence, $L=0$.

**why $f(1)$ is not well-defined:**
For an arbitrary number $c \in \mathbb{R}$ there is certainly an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|2^n \cdot f\big(\frac{1}{2^n}\big)|\geq c$, if $L \neq 0$. So $|f(1)| \geq c$ for every $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Please explain "you can conclude that f(1) is not well-defined"

Comment: @user Seriously, what is there left to explain?

Comment: @user1942348 I edited my answer

Comment: What if $f(x) = e^x$? Then the limit is $x \to 0$ is $1$.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Thank you. Would you please elaborate the 2ns part also

Comment: @H.H. this is not a problem at all. in that case also $2^n e^{\frac{1}{2^n}} \to \infty$. beside the fact that this function isn't additive.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek You're right, it's not additive. I don't know where my mind was when I made that comment.

Comment: @user1942348 for the second question you can use the hint of the other answer by Vizag.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$ \lim_{x\to a}f(x)= \lim_{ h \to 0} f(a+h) = \lim_{h \to 0} (f(a) + f(h))$$

Comment: this helps to prove the second question but this doesn't explain that $L = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x + x)$ (because as $x \to 0$ then also $x + x \to 0$)

$= \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) + \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$.

Hence $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = 0$.

Furthermore, after proving the limit at $0$ exists, we can use this information to prove the limit at everypoint also exists:

$\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0) + \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x - x_0) = f(x_0)$, because asking what $\lim_{x \to x_0}$ is the same as asking what $\lim_{x - x_0 \to 0}$ is.